How to filter dataframe based on array of index
I am using Python
X is a dataframe that has these values
In [29]: X
Out[29]: 
         RepID
76758   207355
5787     15900
101140  273993
96040   260308
82096   221946
65858   178020
40664   109821
56044   151664
76522   206735
12478    33774

test_indices is an array that has index numbers
In [30]: test_indices
Out[30]: array([7, 8])

I am trying to filter X into a new variable called X_test
where X_test is the records of indecies in test_indices
I tried this
X_test = X[test_indices]

but I got an error
KeyError: "None of [Index([7, 8], dtype='int32')] are in the [columns]"

how to fix this problem

It should be X.loc[test_indices]. But you'll get an error if any of the values in test_indices aren't in the index of the dataframe.

usually the index is row numbers. Why are your indexes so random?

Perhaps you mean to select by index positions? If so, use X.iloc[test_indices]. In general, on indexing and selecting see this post and the linked docs (and other posts) there.

You can use isin():
X_test = X[df.index.isin(a)]

